# Problems with making an Android calculator app

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and I am trying to make a simple calculator app that takes two operands and either adds, subtracts, multiplies, or divides them. The problem I am having is when I hit equals after entering in the correct format, it gives me a result of 0 or 1. I think it is comparing objects together and returning 0 if it isn't the same and 1 if it is the same, but I have no idea which objects it is comparing. What am I doing wrong?

This is my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.simplecalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener
{

    private EditText output;
    private Button num_0;
    private Button num_1;
    private Button num_2;
    private Button num_3;
    private Button num_4;
    private Button num_5;
    private Button num_6;
    private Button num_7;
    private Button num_8;
    private Button num_9;
    private Button op_plus;
    private Button op_minus;
    private Button op_multiply;
    private Button op_divide;
    private Button equals;
    private Button clear;
    private long operand1;
    private long operand2;
    private long result;
    private String operator;
    private StringBuilder set1;
    private StringBuilder set2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        operator = "";
        operand1 = -1;
        operand2 = -1;
        set1 = new StringBuilder();
        set2 = new StringBuilder();
        output = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.output);
        num_0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.num_0);
        num_1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.num_1);
        num_2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.num_2);
        num_3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.num_3);
        num_4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.num_4);
        num_5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.num_5);
        num_6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.num_6);
        num_7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.num_7);
        num_8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.num_8);
        num_9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.num_9);
        op_plus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.op_plus);
        op_minus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.op_minus);
        op_multiply = (Button)findViewById(R.id.op_multiply);
        op_divide = (Button)findViewById(R.id.op_divide);
        equals = (Button)findViewById(R.id.equals);
        clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);

        num_0.setOnClickListener(this);
        num_1.setOnClickListener(this);
        num_2.setOnClickListener(this);
        num_3.setOnClickListener(this);
        num_4.setOnClickListener(this);
        num_5.setOnClickListener(this);
        num_6.setOnClickListener(this);
        num_7.setOnClickListener(this);
        num_8.setOnClickListener(this);
        num_9.setOnClickListener(this);
        op_plus.setOnClickListener(this);
        op_minus.setOnClickListener(this);
        op_multiply.setOnClickListener(this);
        op_divide.setOnClickListener(this);
        equals.setOnClickListener(this);
        clear.setOnClickListener(this);     
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.num_0:
                output.append(num_0.getText());
                if(operand1 == -1)
                {
                    set1.append(num_0.getText().toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    set2.append(num_0.getText().toString());
                }
                break;

            case R.id.num_1:
                output.append(num_1.getText());
                if(operand1 == -1)
                {
                    set1.append(num_1.getText().toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    set2.append(num_1.getText().toString());
                    operand2 = Long.parseLong(set2.toString());
                }
                break;

            case R.id.num_2:
                output.append(num_2.getText());
                if(operand1 == -1)
                {
                    set1.append(num_2.getText().toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    set2.append(num_2.getText().toString());
                }
                break;

            case R.id.num_3:
                output.append(num_3.getText());
                if(operand1 == -1)
                {
                    set1.append(num_3.getText().toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    set2.append(num_3.getText().toString());
                }
                break;

            case R.id.num_4:
                output.append(num_4.getText());
                if(operand1 == -1)
                {
                    set1.append(num_4.getText().toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    set2.append(num_4.getText().toString());
                }
                break;

            case R.id.num_5:
                output.append(num_5.getText());
                if(operand1 == -1)
                {
                    set1.append(num_5.getText().toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    set2.append(num_5.getText().toString());
                }
                break;

            case R.id.num_6:
                output.append(num_6.getText());
                if(operand1 == -1)
                {
                    set1.append(num_6.getText().toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    set2.append(num_6.getText().toString());
                }
                break;

            case R.id.num_7:
                output.append(num_7.getText());
                if(operand1 == -1)
                {
                    set1.append(num_7.getText().toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    set2.append(num_7.getText().toString());
                }
                break;

            case R.id.num_8:
                output.append(num_8.getText());
                if(operand1 == -1)
                {
                    set1.append(num_8.getText().toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    set2.append(num_8.getText().toString());
                }
                break;

            case R.id.num_9:
                output.append(num_9.getText());
                if(operand1 == -1)
                {
                    set1.append(num_9.getText().toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    set2.append(num_9.getText().toString());
                }
                break;

            case R.id.op_plus:
                if(operand1 == -1)
                {
                    operator = "+";
                    operand1 = Long.parseLong(set1.toString());
                    output.append(operator);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.op_minus:
                if(operand1 == -1)
                {
                    operator = "-";
                    operand1 = Long.parseLong(set1.toString());
                    output.append(operator);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.op_multiply:
                if(operand1 == -1)
                {
                    operator = "*";
                    operand1 = Long.parseLong(set1.toString());
                    output.append(operator);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.op_divide:
                if(operand1 == -1)
                {
                    operator = "/";
                    operand1 = Long.parseLong(set1.toString());
                    output.append(operator);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.equals:
                operand2 = Long.parseLong(set2.toString());
                switch(operator)
                {
                    case "+":
                        result = operand1 + operand2;

                    case "-":
                        result = operand1 - operand2;

                    case "*":
                        result = operand1 * operand2;

                    case "/":
                        result = operand1 / operand2;
                }
                output.setText(""+result);
                operator = null;
                operand1 = -1;
                operand2 = -1;
                set1.setLength(0);
                set2.setLength(0);
                break;

            case R.id.clear:
                output.setText("");
                operator = null;
                operand1 = -1;
                operand2 = -1;
                set1.setLength(0);
                set2.setLength(0);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And this is my activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.simplecalculator.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/output"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/start_value">  
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/num_7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/num_7">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/num_8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/num_8">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/num_9"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/num_9">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/op_plus"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/op_plus">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/num_4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/num_4">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/num_5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/num_5">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/num_6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/num_6">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/op_minus"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/op_minus">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/num_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/num_1">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/num_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/num_2">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/num_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/num_3">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/op_multiply"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/op_multiply">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/num_0"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/num_0">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/clear">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equals"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/equals">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/op_divide"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/op_divide">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: Here is my strings.xml file as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">SimpleCalculator</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="start_value"></string>
    <string name="num_0">0</string>
    <string name="num_1">1</string>
    <string name="num_2">2</string>
    <string name="num_3">3</string>
    <string name="num_4">4</string>
    <string name="num_5">5</string>
    <string name="num_6">6</string>
    <string name="num_7">7</string>
    <string name="num_8">8</string>
    <string name="num_9">9</string>
    <string name="op_plus">+</string>
    <string name="op_minus">-</string>
    <string name="op_multiply">*</string>
    <string name="op_divide">/</string>
    <string name="clear">C</string>
    <string name="equals">=</string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figured it out. I didn't have a `break` statement in my equals `switch` statement after each case. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score -1):

Probably your `android:text="@string/num_7` is wrong, is `@string/num_7` actually the button for the output? It's possible that you have set the button for number 1 output, check again!

Comment: No, Button equals is number =, not @string/num_7